# retrieve containers start order in docker

Tags: docker, dependencies, containers

I know how to use depends_on in docker-compose file. But I've inherited a running docker infrastructure without any documentation. How can I retrieve the dependencies among containers? I've no docker-compose.yaml file available. I tried with docker inspect but the result does not give me any information about dependencies of the single container.

Comment: what do you mean by "dependencies among containers"?

Comment: the value of depends_on in the docker-compose file. The starting order, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

In the default location `./docker-compose.yml` is where the file would be stored.

These commands you can also try are,

```
docker ps -a | grep (certain_container)
locate docker-compose.yml to find the file you would like
docker-compose restart (run the docker-compose command to see options)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I haven't found docker-compose.yml for all containers via locate or find. But for sure I know that two container (for which I have no docker-compose file) have a specific starting order. I cannot find anything in docker documentation.

Comment: If it's two containers only, do you know each containers main process? Is it an application on one container, and then a database on the other container?

Comment: Not only. On the server there are about 20 containers. Each container serve a specific service. Some services are exposed to Internet and others are used as support services but the exposed ones. This is why I need to know the correct start order. I'm not able to find where docker stores this information and an API/CLI that allows me to retrieve it.